# TSLint: how to ignore JS files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

How can I tell tslint to ignore JS files?

In `tsconfig.json` I have `"allowJs": true` because I do want it to compile JS files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "allowJs": true,
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

However I do not want it to lint them.

With this setup, it complains that *"No valid rules have been specified for JavaScript files"*. This is because it tries to lint JS files, but has not been given any rules for doing so.

It has been suggested in another Stack Overflow thread to add the following, so that it has *some* rules to go by (a bit of a hack really):

```
"jsRules": {
    "no-empty": true
}
```

But what if I don't want it to check for this rule either? I just don't want it to lint JS files at all.

Answer (score 2):

I've found out how to do this.

To ignore JS files, add the following to your `tslint.json` (you can, of course, ignore any file type in a similar fashion)

```
"linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.js"
    ]
}
```

Note that `linterOptions.exclude` was introduced in tslint 5.8, so you must have this version or later to use this feature.